# Pick error "Type 'Pick<TypeObject, "...">' cannot be used as an index type."

Tags: typescript, axios

Trying to modify my axios wrapper and can't figure out why I'm getting this typescript error...

```
type Headers = {
  Accept: string;
  'Content-Type': string;
  Authorization?: string;
}

export interface AxiosOptions {
  params?: any;
  data?: any;
  headers: Headers;
}

const axiosOptions: AxiosOptions = {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
};

export const updateAxiosOptionsHeaders = (
    key: Pick<Headers, "Accept" | "Content-Type" | "Authorization">,
    value: string
  ): void => {
  axiosOptions.headers[key] = value;
}
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Unclear why you're using `Pick` here. Don't you just need `keyof Headers`?

Comment: @RobbyCornelissen Thanks, I originally tried string, and that didn't work, so I was trying pick. It looks like `key: keyof Headers,` is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't really meet the usage pattern of [`Pick`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktype-keys). You just need `keyof Headers` for your case:

```
type Headers = {
  Accept: string;
  'Content-Type': string;
  Authorization?: string;
}

export interface AxiosOptions {
  params?: any;
  data?: any;
  headers: Headers;
}

const axiosOptions: AxiosOptions = {
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
};

export const updateAxiosOptionsHeaders = (
    key: keyof Headers,
    value: string
  ): void => {
  axiosOptions.headers[key] = value;
}
```

[Playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=25&ssc=2&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAEhCGATCAnAzlAvFA3gKCigEEBjEiMYALijWBQEsA7AcwG4CoByAYQHsmwCIIC0AFXAQuNOo1YdCRAK7AAFn0YAveMAYCA-DPrN2eAL548EAB5gNwKMyEoAZvHLFretAHlKepgx8QjB4FHgAWzRDKHgmEAUoRB14GLiEzlUEZHQaOCRUNA4LPBIBOlivPl9-cpoiKprdcqxcTOzCmmDCYjIKam54MDAAGwYSHQCAegArNAEuABpOQl4BIVEJSGlB4bGJ5qZZ+aYlzjNlsw4rW3soMsCHJTBkoQbvP0O0fJyMbAAKFZQADWEBANFBID4LlgHXQyx6UAAbvARkoIEY5CxOABKGhIvgMRBYAB8bUI8EanwCaAAdFkCugANqQgC6rRRaIgxSAA)

---

Should you also have different value types in your object (which seems unlikely for a headers object), you can use a [generic constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints):

```
export const updateAxiosOptionsHeaders = <K extends keyof Headers>(
    key: K,
    value: Headers[K]
  ): void => {
  axiosOptions.headers[key] = value;
}
```

Comment: Ty for answer follow up for others who view this. That's what I did too(1st demo). Also thanks for explaining the 2nd solution. I refactored to that in case any values are something other than a `string`.